# TimerTrigger that executes instantly and then every 5 minutes

Tags: c#, .net, azure

In this document ([Timer trigger for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer#c-example)) the example they give executes the function every five minutes, starting with the minutes that end in 5 or 0. That's fine, but unless I'm missing something, this document does not explain the syntax of the trigger and how I can customize it.

```
  public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
  {
      ....
  }
```

For testing purposes on my localhost, this is really annoying to have wait until my clock time is a minute that ends in 5 or 0. I just want the function to execute immediately when run, and then again every five minutes after that.  How would I modify this syntax accordingly?

Comment: Read more about CRON Expressions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer#cron-expressions)

Comment: @Matt.G, ok yeah, I just didn't scroll down far enough in the document. However, I think I need to set 'RunOnStartup' to true. Just gotta figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just pass `RunOnStartup = true` when using the attribute:

```
[TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)]
```

Comment: Sorry @Matt.G. Every five minutes after startup is fine. Typo in OP. Fixed

Comment: @haim770: "The type or namespace RunOnStartup could not be found"

Comment: Ah, ok. I misread this at first glance.  Yes, this is the answer.  I'll just need to figure out how to set it to False in prod.

Comment: How about `if #DEBUG`?

Comment: Ok, not getting it figured out!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55362558/programmatically-set-runonstartup-in-azure-function

Comment: Just wante to mention that Azure recommends to NOT use `RunOnStartup` in production