# Programmatically set RunOnStartup in Azure Function?

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I'm creating an Azure function. While testing on my localhost, I'd like it to execute immediately.  But in Prod, it can run every 5 minutes. I'd like to not have to rely on humans to remember to make this change.

```
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)])
```

I've been playing around with various ways to make the `true` here somehow variable, but have not found a solution.  I was thinking something like:

```
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *", RunOnStartup = #DEBUG ? true : false)])
```

But inline #DEBUG is not allowed.

Comment: This post may be useful to you: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45026215/how-to-check-azure-function-is-running-on-local-environment-roleenvironment-i)

Comment: @RyanWilson, ok... seems clunky and error prone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For better readability, you can define a constant `bool` that denotes whether you're running a DEBUG build:

```
#if DEBUG
    const bool IS_DEBUG = true;
#else
    const bool IS_DEBUG = false;
#endif
```

Then use it in your attribute:

```
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *", RunOnStartup = IS_DEBUG)])
```